# How can i create new Contact in Android by Java?

Tags: java, android

I am using Android 3.1 platform and i just want to create new contact on my Emulator using java.I couldn't find any working example.Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the official guide has a good tutorial on adding to the Contacts. Check here : http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html